# Fullcalendar time issue

Tags: salesforce, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using fullcalendar in Salesforce.
There is this custom form created in salesforce in which user enter date and time in custom field which further creates a event in calendar on the specified date from form.

The issue is when I create event using agendaweek it saves the record using form for the specified date and time but when switching to month view and on  manually adding the time it saves the event in calendar 5:30 hours behind.

I consoled output

```
End_Date_time__c":"2021-05-10T06:30:00.000Z","Start_Date_time__c":"2021-05-10T05:30:00.000Z"
```

I tried solving this issue by changing the timzone using following line which allows me to save as per the requirement but it changes the timezone of agendaweek making it 5:30 hours ahead because of the below specified line.

```
 josnArr[i].start = new Date(josnArr[i].start).toLocaleString(undefined, {timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'});
```

If anyone could please suggest something.This is the [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF7RF.png) which I have used to create records in calendar.

Comment: We're not going to be able to solve anything properly without seeing the code which creates the events in each of the two cases you mentioned. Also it's unclear where/when you got that console output, so please highlight that in any code you post. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. the `Z` in those times means "Zulu time" - or in modern terminology UTC. Seems like you want it in `Asia/Kolkata` time. So maybe specify the correct timezone to whatever code is creating that data. It's unclear what/where that is, due to the lack of detail provided.

Comment: P.P.S. As you're new to StackOverflow (welcome!) 
I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks.